# Python list zeroth element mix up

Tags: python, list, zero

I want to write a function decode(chmod) that takes a three digit permissions number as a string and returns the permissions that it grants.
It seems to be working unless I ask for the zeroth element. I couldn't figure out why so.

```
def decode(chmod):

    liste = [int(i)for i in str(chmod)]


    chmod = ["None", "Execute only", "Write only", 
        "Write and Execute", "Read only", 
        "Read and Execute", "Read and Write",
        "Read Write and Execute"] 

    for i in liste:

        print chmod[i]

    return liste

print decode(043)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you want to pass an integer)

043 is base 8 is same as 35 in base 10. You are therefore passing the integer 35 to the decode function.

Try changing the `str` -> `oct`

```
liste = [int(i) for i in oct(chmod)[2:]] #Use [2:] in Py3, and [1:] in Py2
```

Comment: Or just `liste = oct(chmod)`, as `for i in liste` will iterate through each symbol.

Comment: You probably want `oct(chmod)[2:]` to cut off the `0o` prefix. Or perhaps `format(chmod, '03o')` to make sure you always get a three-digit octal string.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Thanks, I missed the fact that it is `043` in Py2, and `0o43` in Py3. Updated my answer. :)

Comment: @AArias: May be `map(int, oct(chmod)[2:])`, but not `liste = oct(chmod)`. Every element needs to be an integer according to OP's code.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan: And I missed / forgot the fact that Python 2 just gives a `0` prefix rather than a `0o` prefix ... :-) Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around 043. Try '043'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm not supposed to be involved with the input. I was only testing whether it works.

Comment: When python sees 043, it thinks it is an integer in octal format. Your decode function will get that intger. Doing str() on it is not what you want. If you want to pass the octal integer, you should convert it back to an octal string rep. (str() not enough).

Comment: @grv: The description you wrote says: "takes a three digit permissions number **as a string** ". But in your test, you're not passing a string; you're passing an integer. Hence the need for quotes.